# Bash - check if I have write permissions to parent of the any directory path

Tags: bash

In my bash script I have to create bunch of directories (NOT files) - `/opt/some/path1/` and `/opt/some/path2/` and so on.

**Please note:** In my case,  `/opt/some/`, the parent already exists, guaranteed. No validation required here.

How can I check if have write permissions to parent for my every `mkdir /opt/some/path1/` and `mkdir /opt/some/path2/`...?

I learned that we can use `-w` for files so I tried this:

```
if [ -w /opt/some/path1/ ]; then echo "You have directory creation permissions"; else echo "You are having a rough day.!"; fi
```

Which "obviously fails" miserably because the directory I am going to create (the path), does not exist yet.

Is there a way we can use something `similar to -w for files` for directories? Or what I am missing here?

Comment: To summarize, you want to check if you're able to create a directory (or file) in a given directory?

Comment: I want to check if I am able to create a directory (NOT file) in a given directory without actually creating the directory. I mean before hand.

Comment: Ok; please note that, as far as I know, files or directories are quite the same on *nix systems, so if you can create files, then you can create directories:) That's why I added files in my 1st comment

Comment: Why not simply doing a `mkdir -p` and then checking the return code to see whether creation was successful? Otherwise, you can use `dirname` to get the directory portion of a path, i.e. `dirname /opt/some/path` writes `/opt/some` to stdout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to check whether you have write access to the directory you want to create a subdirectory of, i.e. before creating `/opt/some/path1/` you'd check write access to `/opt/some/`. You can do that by using the `dirname` command to get the parent directory's path, then using the `-w` test on *that*. Note that `mkdir` still might fail for reasons other than permissions on the parent directory, so you still need to check it for errors. Something like this:

```
dirToCreate=/opt/some/path1/
if [ ! -w "$(dirname "$dirToCreate")" ]; then
    echo "Insufficient permissions to create $dirToCreate" >&2
else
    mkdir "$dirToCreate" || {
        echo "Error creating $dirToCreate (due to something other than permissions)" >&2
    }
fi
```

Comment: Yay...!! worked perfectly as expected. `dirname` was the killer which I was missing and I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ mkdir d1
$ [[ -w d1 ]] && echo Y
Y
$ mkdir d1/d11
$ chmod a-w d1
$ [[ ! -w d1 ]] && echo N
N
$ mkdir d1/d12
mkdir: d1/d12: Permission denied
```

you can check on a dir, which after all is a file

Comment: What I understood here is, that there is no way we can check without actually creating the directory i.e. without doing  `mkdir` first? Is that a correct understanding?

Comment: Updated. I think this is what you are asking, and of course you can't check the permissions on a file or directory that does not exist yet

Comment: Okay. Then how can I assing `[[ -w d1 ]] && echo Y` to a variable? So that I can check if it is `Y` or something else?

Comment: `[[ -w d1 ]]` is the test, so you can write `if [[ -w d1 ]]; then...` see `help test`